# GoalSeek from Excell to python

Tags: python

i need to find "pl" i read that with pyxll i could do it but i cant figure out how... i tried to do it with a for until i get 0.9 but it is very slow...

```
x = 5625000
y = 0.186
z = 0.9

for i in range(1, 40000000):
  pl = x/(y*i)
  
  print(pl, '|', i)
```

this is the formula
5625000/(0.186*pl) = 0.9

i know that pl is = 33601359, thats what it gives on excel

btw, this is macro that i have

```
Sub GoalSeek()
'
' GoalSeek Macro
'
    Range("N4").GoalSeek Goal:=0.9, ChangingCell:=Range("M4")
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't understood your question, can you please explain clearly if possible with more examples. :)

Comment: i need to iterate until pl = 0.9; on excel i have a macro doing Seekgoal until pl gets to 0.9

Like, when 5625000 / (0.186*PL) = 0.9 so i need to iterate PL until i get as a result 0.9 and then save that pl number, on excel i´m using GoalSeek to find that number and it is very fast. but in python idk how to do it, i tried with a for but its very slow... this the post i found talking about pyxll
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-better-excel-goal-seek-using-python-fb6aff56e9f2
but i cant get it to work... any idea on how to do it?


srry for my english... i speak spanish as main language

Comment: Thanks so much for ur time, did u understood??